# Is there a more efficient XQuery here for deletion?

Tags: xml, xquery, exist-db

I have a large eXist-db database in which I am implementing some functions to manage the data inside.

The pertinent information here is:

There are 2000 customers.
Each customer has access to 400 documents.
Now each document has 20 languages.

So I have 2000 XMLs, each have something like this:

```
<customer name="foo">
    <document num="A01" subscribed="Y">
      <languages>
        <lang subscribed="N">Arabic</lang>
        <lang subscribed="Y">Polish</lang>
... and so on for 400 documents for 20 languages ...
```

Now I an trying to write an xQuery because I need to revoke a language. This means I need to essentially delete in 2000 files, for every document, the <lang> whose name is defined.

So something like this:

```
 for $langs in $g:collection.customers//lang[text()=$deletelang]
 return update delete $langs
```

But this is taking forever and actually requires a huge amount of memory. Certainly in looking at it ... $langs would be 2000*400 = 800,000 items.

I would note that a range index exists which contains:

```
<create qname="lang" type="xs:string" nested="no"/>
```

But still, is that delete query so inefficient that essentially it cannot execute with 800,000 items or is there some other way that should be written?

**Update I**

So I changed things a bit to just see.

1) Per the comment, I changed to "." from text()

2) I added subsequence() surrounding this to test various sizes>>

```
for $langs in subsequence($g:collection.customers//lang[.=$deletelang],1,30000)
```

1-30000 = 24s

so running the whole collection now = 110s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to profile the query to determine exactly where it's spending the most time, but it's possible that your use of `text()` is short-circuiting the engine's ability to use the range index and is therefore loading all those documents into memory.

`text()` selects text nodes, and there may be more that one text node in an element. i.e: `element lang { text { 'Pol' }, text { 'ish' } }` will result in an element that looks like `<lang>Polish</lang>`, but has two text nodes and will fail on a predicate that assumes there is only one: `[text() = 'Polish']`.

Try using dot in your predicate: `[. = $deletelang]`.

It's also possible that there is additional overhead in the database to committing such a large update at once. If it is not critical that the delete be done atomically, you may improve performance by batching the updates.

Comment: I will test "." and let you know. The same query handles adding a new language as well as deleting it. Adding a new language took 6 mins. Deleting what we just added has never successfully run because it runs out of memory and we have to recover.

Comment: Oh, I can also add that there is no way that there are additional text nodes as we create the node in code and not that way.

Comment: @KevinBrown Yes, but just because you can guarantee that the query is accurate in practice, does not mean that the database can.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've had to do mass deletions. But at least in eXist version 2.2 I could do:

```
let $langs := $g:collection.customers//lang[.=$deletelang]
return update delete $langs
```

There was no need to loop through them all.

On a separate note, I would do a complete backup before issuing such mass deletions, just to make sure that everything goes right.

Hope this helps.